# Unable to use Push segue with Storyboard

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue, pushviewcontroller

Hi I have a Tab Bar controller that open a Table View Controller.

Then, clicking a row, I would like to open another ViewController with push method (I need to view new window from right... like an email).
But I receive always an error on push. I've also used the option. "Editor ->Embedded in -> navigartion controller" for table view, but without luck...
Any idea?

Comment: Make sure the segue is connected property with the table view cell.

Comment: Hi... yes it is. In fact if I switch to modal segue all works fine.
The error is: "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"
...if I make this chain TabBar->TableView->ViewController
2)